# How to fire oncheckedchanged event for @Html.CheckBoxFor in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How can I fire the `oncheckedchanged` event with the following code?

View:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Baseline, new { @class = "formCheckbox", tabindex = "24"})
```

Model:

```
public bool Baseline { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `oncheckedchanged` event is a webforms event rather than MVC. If you want to capture the change event, you can do that using javascript. Here's an example using jquery:

```
(function($) {
    $('#Baseline').on("change", function(e) {
        // do stuff relating to change event here
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.But is there any way to fire this event with MVC helper class?

Comment: Not without writing your own implementation of the helper. Even then I wouldn't recommend it. How are you wanting to use the event? There isn't really the concept of a postback in MVC, so the way that you have to think about creating applications is a bit different.